# Validator for MethodArgumentNotValidException only handles constraint of same type

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm trying to validate my form against constraints set on my bean. Spring-MVC version i am using is 3.2.4. The problem is that default Spring validator does not validate all constraints; only the ones that are of the same type.

I have the following controller code:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes()
public class FormSubmitController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelMap saveForm(@Valid @RequestBody Form form, HttpSession session) {
        session.setAttribute("form", form);
        ModelMap map = new ModelMap();
        map.addAttribute("hasErrors", false);
        return map;
    }
}
```

and the following bean:

```
public class Form implements IForm, Serializable {

    @NotNull(message = "Category should not be empty")
    protected String category;
    @NotNull(message = "Sub-Category should not be empty")
    protected String subCategory;

    @Size(min=0, message="Firstname should not be empty")
    protected String firstName;
    @Size(min=0, message="Lastname should not be empty")
    protected String lastName;

   @Pattern(regexp="^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$",     message="Date of birth should be in dd-mm-jjjj format")
    protected String dateOfBirth;

    //getters and setters
}
```

The handler for MethodArgumentNotValidException looks like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class FormExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelMap     handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException error) {
        List<FieldError> errors = error.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();
        ModelMap map = new ModelMap();
        ModelMap errorMap = new ModelMap();
        map.addAttribute("hasErrors", true);
        for (FieldError fieldError : errors) {
            errorMap.addAttribute(fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        map.addAttribute("bindingErrors", errorMap);
        return map;
    }
}
```

So, an empty form results in the first two error messages.
The firts two properties of the form filled results in the third and fourth error messages.

Only when i use the same contraint type (i.e. NotNull) for all properties on my bean it will return all error messages.

What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong the validator for [@Size](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.2.0.CR1/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/impl/SizeValidatorForString.java) and [@Pattern](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.2.0.Final/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/impl/PatternValidator.java#PatternValidator) by default accept null as valid. So you actually need both annotations (@NotNull and @Pattern/@Size). These annotations only trigger validation of values which are non-null, these validations don't imply that `null` values are invalid that is where the `@NotNull` is for.

This is assuming you are using hibernate-vaildator (as that is the out-of-the-box supported validator).